# UDP multi client server basics

Tags: c, linux, udp

I'm looking forward to achive this: Server recieves from number of clients a string(file name) which he has to take from the folder and return it to the the client by a bufferSize which is defined from the command line. It has to be implemented with UDP communication. i'm familiarized with TCP sockets, but i don't get how can i get a fileDescriptor for the udp connection since accepts is missing.

So I'm thinking about this: after the config i do a while-loop in the server where i get 'some kind of descriptor' which i'll send to a new thread which knows  where to send the data back... Any ideas?

I've checked the net but didn't found a concrete explanation for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found something helpful,  maybe it will be useful for others so here it is: the code is commented and really clear.
PS: sorry for the long paste, but google doesn't let me copy the link.

```
    /* 
 * udpserver.c - A simple UDP echo server 
 * usage: udpserver <port>
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

/*
 * error - wrapper for perror
 */
void error(char *msg) {
  perror(msg);
  exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int sockfd; /* socket */
  int portno; /* port to listen on */
  int clientlen; /* byte size of client's address */
  struct sockaddr_in serveraddr; /* server's addr */
  struct sockaddr_in clientaddr; /* client addr */
  struct hostent *hostp; /* client host info */
  char buf[BUFSIZE]; /* message buf */
  char *hostaddrp; /* dotted decimal host addr string */
  int optval; /* flag value for setsockopt */
  int n; /* message byte size */

  /* 
   * check command line arguments 
   */
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }
  portno = atoi(argv[1]);

  /* 
   * socket: create the parent socket 
   */
  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR opening socket");

  /* setsockopt: Handy debugging trick that lets 
   * us rerun the server immediately after we kill it; 
   * otherwise we have to wait about 20 secs. 
   * Eliminates "ERROR on binding: Address already in use" error. 
   */
  optval = 1;
  setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 
         (const void *)&optval , sizeof(int));

  /*
   * build the server's Internet address
   */
  bzero((char *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
  serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  serveraddr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)portno);

  /* 
   * bind: associate the parent socket with a port 
   */
  if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, 
       sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0) 
    error("ERROR on binding");

  /* 
   * main loop: wait for a datagram, then echo it
   */
  clientlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
  while (1) {

    /*
     * recvfrom: receive a UDP datagram from a client
     */
    bzero(buf, BUFSIZE);
    n = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0,
         (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, &clientlen);
    if (n < 0)
      error("ERROR in recvfrom");

    /* 
     * gethostbyaddr: determine who sent the datagram
     */
    hostp = gethostbyaddr((const char *)&clientaddr.sin_addr.s_addr, 
              sizeof(clientaddr.sin_addr.s_addr), AF_INET);
    if (hostp == NULL)
      error("ERROR on gethostbyaddr");
    hostaddrp = inet_ntoa(clientaddr.sin_addr);
    if (hostaddrp == NULL)
      error("ERROR on inet_ntoa\n");
    printf("server received datagram from %s (%s)\n", 
       hostp->h_name, hostaddrp);
    printf("server received %d/%d bytes: %s\n", strlen(buf), n, buf);

    /* 
     * sendto: echo the input back to the client 
     */
    n = sendto(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0, 
           (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, clientlen);
    if (n < 0) 
      error("ERROR in sendto");
  }
}
```

Comment: The file can be found at: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f99/www/class26/udpserver.c

Answer (score 5):

You don't get connections with UDP; you use [`sendto()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sendto.html) and [`recvfrom()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recvfrom.html) to send and receive messages.

So the server will call `recvfrom()` on the socket; unwrap the request from the data it receives, do the appropriate actions, and use `sendto()` to send the response back to the client from which the request was received.

The client will call `sendto()` to package a message to the server, and then call `recvfrom()` to get the response.  Note that UDP is an unreliable protocol; there is no guarantee that each message will be delivered.  The client has to implement timeouts in case the server dropped a UDP request.  Servers have to be able to deal with duplicate requests, too.