# What is the best approach for designing UDP Server?

Tags: linux, sockets, server, udp

Let's suppose there is a server dealing with multiple clients.
And there is worlds consist of 6 clients.

I think there are 3 approach for designing this server

1. one socket for entire receiving task, another socket for entire sending task.
2. one socket for entire receiving task, allocate sending socket for each world associated with 6 clients.
3. receiving socket for each world, sending socket for each world

Which is the best?
( Of course. there can be other approaches )

Sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

You can receive/send on the same socket.

Take a look at [UDP multi client server basics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731924/udp-multi-client-server-basics)

I dont know the application or what your are trying to do but:

3) It would require that clients send to different ports since you can only listen with 1 socket per port

2) Why allocate a new socket, just use the same socket with udp you can use sendto

1) same as above

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, What I want to talk about are performances of each approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesnt answer precisely your question, but because it's about performance, I thought I'd give my input.

If you want performance, you have to consider that 1 thread can only move information along a pipe so fast, and your server very likely is multi core, so why not use everything you have?

UDP Send should be on one thread. It's job is to loop around a Queue-style container (First In - First Out). it should take a constructed packet and send it, and that's it. To prevent it from wasting cycles spinning for nothing, you can either use Sleep(1), which is also wasteful (and doesn't actually only sleep for 1ms), or implement Thread Signaling (generally better for performance).

In another thread, possibly the main thread, Packets are constructed through an OpCode Assembly Line with the data (encrypted or not) and placed on the Queue, where the UDP Send thread will pick it up once it's scheduled.

Same thing for UDP Receive, separate thread, signaling based on socket state or Sleep(1). Passes packet on to OpCode Stripping Line.

You only need 1 socket for the whole UDP communication with clients.

I write my sockets as non-Blocking. Blocking Sockets can work for Login Servers, if separate, or patch Servers, because their only purpose in life is to accept socket connections.

Hope this helps.